# How to construct HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS in native server push functionality, HttpDeclarePush

Tags: iis

I am trying to implement iis native server push functionality, HTTPDeclarePush, in VC++. Below is the syntax for HttpDeclarePush (from msdn).

```
ULONG WINAPI HttpDeclarePush(

     _In_     HANDLE                RequestQueueHandle,

     _In_     HTTP_REQUEST_ID       RequestId,

     _In_     HTTP_VERB             Verb,

     _In_     PCWSTR                Path,

     _In_opt_ PCSTR                 Query,

     _In_opt_ PHTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS Headers

);
```

While constructing the parameters, I was unable to get the data for the parameter HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS. Can any one please let me know how to construct HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS structure using native C++.